# Return LineStyle from Conditional Format

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to compile a detailed list of conditional formatting with an example of the result.

I need to figure out how to return `True` or `False` on the line style. Or if possible return the line style name (eg xlContinuous). And apply it to the 11th cell.

Commented out is the working part, if it could help anyone.

```
Sub CompileConditionalFormattingList()
    Dim i As Long, cSh As Worksheet, nSh As Worksheet
    Set cSh = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set nSh = Worksheets.Add(After:=cSh)
    With nSh
        .Name = "Format Report"
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 11).Value = _
        Array("Formula", "Interior Color", "Font Color", "Bold", "Italic", "B.Top", "B.Bottom", "B.Left", "B.Right", "Number Format", "Format")

        For i = 1 To cSh.Cells.FormatConditions.Count
            '.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "'" & cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Formula1
            '.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Interior.Color
            '.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Color
            '.Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Bold
            '.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Italic
            .Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle ' I want this to return the line style
            .Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle ' I want this to return the line style
            .Cells(i + 1, 8).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle ' I want this to return the line style
            .Cells(i + 1, 9).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle ' I want this to return the line style
            '.Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat
            With .Cells(i + 1, 11)
                '.Value = "Abc123"
                '.Interior.Color = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Interior.Color
                '.Font.Color = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Color
                '.Font.Bold = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Bold
                '.Font.Italic = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Italic
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle 'Here I want the line style to be replicated
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle 'Here I want the line style to be replicated
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle 'Here I want the line style to be replicated
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle 'Here I want the line style to be replicated
                '.NumberFormat = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code ?

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Do you have something to say about the commented-out portions?

Comment: @Mikku Pasted the wrong version, was tired

Comment: @TimWilliams Pasted the wrong version, figured out parts of it and tried to clarify in the edited version. Commented out is now the part that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal cell can have up to 8 borders (from 5 = xlDiagonalDown to 12 = xlInsideHorizontal),
but a format condition can only have 4 borders (1 = Left, 2 = Right, 3 = Top, 4 = Bottom).

I added an `Iif` condition to show some values explicitly as `True` or `False`.

I set the `ColorIndex` additionally, as a non-filled cell otherwise would be shown with black interior.

```
Sub CompileConditionalFormattingList()
    Dim i As Long, cSh As Worksheet, nSh As Worksheet
    Set cSh = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set nSh = Worksheets.Add(After:=cSh)
    With nSh
        .Name = "Format Report"
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 11).Value = _
        Array("Formula", "Interior Color", "Font Color", "Bold", "Italic", _
            "B.Left", "B.Right", "B.Top", "B.Bottom", "Number Format", "Format")

        For i = 1 To cSh.Cells.FormatConditions.Count
            .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "'" & cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Formula1
            .Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Interior.Color
            .Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Color
            .Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = IIf(cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Bold, True, False)
            .Cells(i + 1, 5).Value = IIf(cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Italic, True, False)
            .Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = GetLinestyleName(cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(1).LineStyle)
            .Cells(i + 1, 7).Value = GetLinestyleName(cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(2).LineStyle)
            .Cells(i + 1, 8).Value = GetLinestyleName(cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(3).LineStyle)
            .Cells(i + 1, 9).Value = GetLinestyleName(cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(4).LineStyle)
            .Cells(i + 1, 10).Value = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat
            With .Cells(i + 1, 11)
                .Value = "Abc123"
                .Interior.Color = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Interior.Color
                .Interior.ColorIndex = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Interior.ColorIndex
                .Font.Color = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Color
                .Font.Bold = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Bold
                .Font.Italic = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Font.Italic
                .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(1).LineStyle
                .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(2).LineStyle
                .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(3).LineStyle
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).Borders(4).LineStyle
                .NumberFormat = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i).NumberFormat
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function GetLinestyleName(i As Long) As String
    Select Case i
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous     ' 1
        GetLinestyleName = "xlContinuous"
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDash           ' -4115
        GetLinestyleName = "xlDash"
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDashDot        ' 4
        GetLinestyleName = "xlDashDot"
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDashDotDot     ' 5
        GetLinestyleName = "xlDashDotDot"
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDot            ' -4118
        GetLinestyleName = "xlDot"
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDouble         ' -4119
        GetLinestyleName = "xlDouble"
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone  ' -4142
        GetLinestyleName = "xlLineStyleNone"
    Case Excel.XlLineStyle.xlSlantDashDot   ' 13
        GetLinestyleName = "xlSlantDashDot"
    Case Else
        GetLinestyleName = "unknown"
    End Select
End Function
```

If you want to see more parameters of a format condition, you can assign it to a variable by this:

```
Dim fc as FormatCondition
...
Set fc = cSh.Cells.FormatConditions(i)
Stop
```

If you stop the code afterwards, you can examine its parameters in the local window.